# Django - initialize many to many fields on database level

Tags: python, django, database, orm, initialization

Example code to start with:

```
In my model:
class X(models.Model):
    someField = models.ManyToManyField(Many_values, related_name='someField')
    ......

In my controller (which is a controller, not a view, get over it, Django!)
    xes = X.objects.filter(iscool=True)   [1]
    .......
    some_function_call(xes)

In some function:
    for x in xes:
        some_table.append(x.someField.first()) [2]
```

Now, is there any way, to enforce django, to get those someField values (or at least, the first one) in the [1] moment?

Right now, I'm storing those values in table at [2], which:

1. Causes immediate database selects every time it's called
2. Seems to cause them every time i call the first() function
3. Is inefficient, since it would be faster, if joined with a [1] database select
4. Forces me to store those first() values in a separate table, and i have to remember that
5. Reminds me, that I'm unable to format my stackoverflow post properly, so this list will most likely be displayed as a plain text

In short, what i want to achieve is:

whenever i call

```
x.someField.first()
```

i want it NOT to look for it in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a view. Django is explicitly not MVC.

But yes, there is a well-documented [`prefetch_related` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
xes = X.objects.filter(iscool=True).prefetch_related('someField')
```